# What is the value of the integral$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t} \, e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have a question about evaluating

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t}  \, e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t$$

---

Since $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}  =0$, we know that the integrand is integrable near $t=0$.

But when evaluating the integral, how do you deal with the $t$ in the denominator of the integrand?

Comment: I hope the method is the simplest:)

Comment: The fact that this question is so heavily upvoted is baffling...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider
$$\mathcal{I}(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos at}{t}e^{-t}dt.$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $a$, we find
$$\mathcal{I}'(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\sin at\;e^{-t}dt=\frac{a}{1+a^2}.$$
Now integrating back and using that $\mathcal{I}(0)=0$ yields
$$\mathcal{I}(a)=\int_0^a\frac{a\,da}{1+a^2}=\frac12\ln\left(1+a^2\right).$$
It remains to set $a=1$.

Comment: You are too fast! :P I solved it by considering $I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t}e^{-at}\,dt$ but I think both the approaches are similar so I didn't post it. :D

Comment: @Paul You are welcome!

Comment: Does this method have a name? I haven't seen an integral evaluated this way before.

Comment: @Achal [Differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). Sometimes people also refer to Feynman.

Comment: What is the justification for moving the differentiation into the integral?

Answer (score 14):

Assume that $a>1$.

Using the Maclaurin series of the cosine function,  we get

$$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t} \, e^{-at} \, dt &= -\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}t^{2n}}{(2n)!} \frac{e^{-at}}{t} \, dt  \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!} \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{2n-1}e^{-at} \, dt \\ &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!} \frac{(2n-1)!}{a^{2n}} \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \left( \frac{1}{a^{2}} \right)^{n} \\ &=\frac{1}{2} \,\ln \left(1+ \frac{1}{a^{2}} \right) \, ,  \end{align}$$ where interchanging the order of summation and integration is justified by [Fubini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83747/).

Letting $a \to 1^{+}$, we get $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t} \, e^{-t} \, dt = \frac{\ln 2}{2}. $$

(See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1519281/16033) about justification for moving the limit inside the integral.)

Comment: Brilliant! +1. Never crossed my mind to use this method. I tried to use Frullani's integral but I couldn't.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: I have posted a solution using Frullani's integral. :)

Comment: And as always, great solution Random Variable! :)

Answer (score 9):

Consider the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos t}{t} e^{-st} dt. $$
If we define $f(t)=1-\cos t$, this integral is the Laplace transform of $f(t)/t$. Moreover, we have the following [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) for Laplace transforms:

$$\mathcal{L} \left\{ \frac{f(t)}{t} \right\}(s)=\int_s^\infty F(\sigma)d \sigma $$
where $F(\sigma)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$, which in our case is known to be $$F(\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma}-\frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2+1}. $$ Thus we have $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos t}{t} e^{-st}=\int_s^\infty \left( \frac{1}{\sigma}-\frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2+1} \right) d \sigma= \log \sigma-\frac{1}{2} \log (\sigma^2+1) \big]^{\sigma=\infty}_{\sigma=s} .$$
Plugging in $s=1$ gives $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos t}{t} e^{-t} dt=\frac{1}{2} \log 2- \log 1=\frac{1}{2} \log 2 .$$

Comment: We have a same approach. I didn't notice your answer because I used my tablet to type the answer. Sorry for that. +1.

Answer (score 8):

**Another approach**

Consider [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[f(t)\right]=F(s)=\int_0^\infty f(t)\ e^{-st}\ dt
$$
and property of the unilateral Laplace transform
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{f(t)}{t}\right]=\int_s^\infty F(\omega)\ d\omega,
$$
where $F(\omega)$ is Laplace transform of $f(t)$. We choose $f(t)=(1-\cos at)$ and it is easy to show that
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[1-\cos at\right]=F(s)=\int_0^\infty (1-\cos at)\ e^{-st}\ dt=\frac{a^2}{s(s^2+a^2)},
$$
then
$$\eqalign
{
\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{1-\cos at}{t}\right]&=\int_1^\infty \frac{a^2}{s(s^2+a^2)}\ ds\\
&=\int_1^\infty \left[\frac{1}{s}-\frac{s}{s^2+a^2}\right]\ ds\\
&=\left.\frac12\left[\ln s^2-\ln(s^2+a^2)\right]\right|_1^\infty\\
&=\left.\frac12\ln\left(\frac{s^2}{s^2+a^2}\right)\right|_1^\infty\\
&=\frac12\ln\left(1+a^2\right).
}
$$
Taking $a=1$ yields
$$
\int_0^\infty \left[\frac{1-\cos t}{t}\right]\ e^{-t}\ dt=\large\color{blue}{\frac{\ln 2}{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using Frullani's integral.

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t}e^{-t}\,dt=\Re\left(\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{it}}{t}e^{-t}\,dt\right)=\Re\left(\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-(1-i)t}}{t}\,dt\right)$$
$$=\Re\left(\ln\left(\frac{1-i}{1}\right)\right)=\Re\left(\ln\left(\sqrt{2}e^{i(-\pi/4+2k\pi)}\right)\right)=\boxed{\dfrac{\ln 2}{2}}$$

Comment: Wait!? I got the result until $\Re[\ln(1-i)]$ but when I used [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=real+part+ln%281-i%29) the answer is $1$. I forgot to use the way that you used. Darn!

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: But still, why does W|A gives 1? Any ideas? :/

Comment: I don't know!? Have you clicked the link?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: Yes, I clicked it and it shows 1 as the answer.

Comment: However, if I enter this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=real+part+ln%28sqrt%282%29e%5E%28ipi%2F4%29%29 it shows the correct result.

Comment: That was obvious Pranav. W|A has tricked me! Since you have reached daily limit rep, I will vote up your answer tommorow. :D

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: Thanks! :D

Comment: @Tunk-Fey $\ln(1-i) = \ln|1-i|+ i \arg(1-i)$.  So no matter what branch of $\log z$ you choose, the real part is always $\frac{\ln 2}{2}$. And if you look at the number line it displays, notice where the dot is. Strange.

Comment: @RandomVariable I only saw the first output & I didn't notice the line nor alternative output. Do you know why the first output W|A is $1$?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey I don't know. It seems to be nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - \cos\pars{t} \over t} \expo{-t}\,\dd t =\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#44f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - \cos\pars{t} \over t} \expo{-t}\,\dd t}
> =\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> \expo{-t} - \expo{-\pars{1 + \ic}t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t\xi}\,\dd\xi\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> \expo{-\pars{1 + \xi}t} - \expo{-\pars{\xi + 1 + \ic}t}}\,\dd t\,\dd\xi
> =\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{{1 \over \xi + 1} - {1 \over \xi + 1 + \ic}}\,\dd\xi
> \\[3mm]&=\Re\ln\pars{1 + \ic} = \color{#44f}{\large\half\,\ln\pars{2}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**By double integral $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t} e^{-t} d t = & \int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^1 \sin (t x) d x\right) e^{-t} d t \\
= & \int_0^1 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \sin (t x) d t d x \\
= & \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+1} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\left[\ln \left(x^2+1\right)\right]_0^1 \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$**