# Convergence of integral of $J_{\nu}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, convergence-divergence, bessel-functions

It is well known that, if $J_{\nu}$ denotes the Bessel function of the first kind, then we have

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} J_{0}(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = 1.$$

Moreover, since $\int J_{1}(x) = -J_{0}(x)$, then we also have

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} J_{1}(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = 1,$$

since $J_{0}(0) = 1$ and $J_{0}$ tends to zero at infinity. Can we say anything similar about $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}J_{\nu}(x)  \ \mathrm{d}x,$ where $\nu > 0$ is either an integer or a half-integer? Do all of these integrals converge? Are they listed somewhere in a table of integrals? Gradshteyn-Ryzhik lists some examples, but they only seem applicable to $\nu = 0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\nu\in\mathbb{N}$, we have:
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(J_\nu(x)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}\left(s+\sqrt{1+s^2}\right)^\nu},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}(1)=\delta(s) \tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}J_\nu(x)\,dx = \lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}\left(s+\sqrt{1+s^2}\right)^\nu} = \color{red}{1}.\tag{2}$$
I exploited [a useful property of the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis). The first identity can be easily derived from the [generating function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) for Bessel functions of the first kind:
$$ \exp\left(\frac{z}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}t^n J_n(z).\tag{3}$$
$(1)$ (then $(2)$) holds also if $\nu\in\mathbb{R}^+$ since $(1)$ follows from [Bessel's differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html), too.

---

Clarification: we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}J_\nu(x)\,dx = \lim_{s\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{+\infty}J_\nu(x)e^{-sx}\,dx $$
since $J_\nu(x)$ is an improperly Riemann-integrable function, because $J_\nu(x)$ is continuous (much more: entire) in a right neighbourhood of the origin and $$J_\nu(x)\approx\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(x-\theta_\nu)$$
for large $x$ (equation $(58)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)), so $\int_{0}^{+\infty}J_\nu(x)\,dx$ is convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), since $\cos(x-\theta_\nu)$ is a function with mean zero.

Comment: The formula you give for the Laplace transform is usually under the condition that the real part of $s$ should be positive. What is the argument that you are allowed to take $s\to 0$?

Comment: @mickep: that should be a $s\to 0^+$, now fixing.

Comment: May I ask the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Let me clarify that I am not the down voter. I still don't see how the validation of the limit $s\to0^+$ follows (I by no means doubt it, but when I in a discussion with a colleague some time ago about this very problem, we (he) ended up with a rather complicated argument.)

Comment: @mickep: in general, $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{s\to 0^+}(\mathcal{L}f)(s)$$ as soon as the dominated convergence theorem ensures $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{s\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x) e^{-sx}\,dx.$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably slow right now. But $J_\nu\not\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, so what is the dominated function in this case?

Comment: @mickep   Since $\int_{0}^{\infty} J_{\nu}(x) \, dx, \ v >-1,$ does not converge absolutely, justification here comes from the fact that the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-p x} \, dx$ converges uniformly on $[0, \infty)$ if  $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ exists as an improper Riemann integral. See Daniel Fischer's answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1519281).

Comment: @RandomVariable: thank you, I was going to tell exactly the same.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you very much, it is now clear. I don't want to put words into the mouth of OP, but I actually got the feeling that it was this convergence that was the main problem. Jack, now when this is sorted out, you certainly get my vote.

Comment: @mickep: I added a clarification, I hope it is clear enough :)