# When can an infinite sum and complex integral be interchanged?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Are there some conditions under which the following two are equal?

$$\displaystyle \oint_C \sum  f_n(z)= \sum \oint_C f_n(z)$$

In the case of real valued functions, the condition $f_n(z) \geq 0$ suffices (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged)). Is there a simple condition like that in the case of complex valued analytic functions with simple/double poles?

Thank you :)

Comment: An analogous condition for complex-valued functions would be the requirement that, for $z \in C$, the functions $f_n(z)$ take values in one, and only one, quadrant.

Comment: Sigh! I want a condition that allows me to run a contour integral around a circle that is centered at origin :(

Comment: Sure, that's fine, what I said still applies.  I've clarified my comment in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform convergence allows you to switch a limit and an integral. So if the $f_n$ converge uniformly to $0$ on $C$ (for instance, if they are the terms of a Laurent series and $C$ is contained inside the annulus of convergence), then $\sum f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on $C$, and it is safe to switch the sum and the integral.

Comment: How would you check if $f_{n}$ converges uniformly, also would the result work if we are integrating $c^{1}$ curves ?

Answer (score 3):

Since

$$
\int_C f(z)\,dz = \int_C \operatorname{Re} f(z)\,dz + i\int_C \operatorname{Im} f(z)\,dz,
$$

you can essentially apply the same criteria in the complex case as in the real case.  Specifically, you just need the real and imaginary parts of the integrands to be single-signed.

Let $Q_j$, $j=1,2,3,4$, denote the four closed quadrants of the complex plane.  If

$$
f_n(z) \in Q_j \quad \text{for all } n \in \mathbb N \text{ and } z \in C
$$

for some $Q_j$ then

$$
\displaystyle \oint_C \sum_n f_n(z)= \sum_n \oint_C f_n(z)
$$

follows from applying the known result for real functions to the real and imaginary parts of the integral.