# Is this equality $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^x \frac{t^2}{2(e^t-1)}\mathrm{d}t=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^3}$ true?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Using a little program in Python, it looks true for at least two hundred digits after the comma, but I have absolutely no idea, how to begin. Any hint sould be appreciate.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^x \frac{t^2}{2(e^t-1)}\mathrm{d}t=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^3}$$

It looks not very difficult, I tried a integration by part but it looks not to be the better way to compute it. I'm stuck there.

I should be glad, thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's true. See e.g. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1092356/147873) for a way to derive it. The gist of the derivation: expand $\frac{1}{e^t-1} = \frac{1}{e^t} \frac{1}{1-e^{-t}}$ in a geometrical series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nt}$ and integrate term by term using the definition of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) to evaluate each integral. The general result is $\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-1}{\rm d}t = \zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$ where $\zeta(s)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: OK, i see, it looks a very funny way, i will do it. I never use the gamma function in my life but it looks in my way. Thank you.

Comment: See this [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/a/7665/54230) for a, imo, particular nice derivation (just take $s=3$ to get your integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This may be more a long comment than an answer.*

In a spirit similar to Winther's comments, it could be of interest to you to know that, using [polylogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) and their properties, $$\int \frac{t^2}{2(e^t-1)}\,{dt}=t \text{Li}_2\left(e^t\right)-\text{Li}_3\left(e^t\right)-\frac{1}{6} t^2 \left(t-3
   \log \left(1-e^t\right)\right)$$ So,$$\int_0^x \frac{t^2}{2(e^t-1)}\,{dt}=x \text{Li}_2\left(e^x\right)-\text{Li}_3\left(e^x\right)-\frac{1}{6} x^2 \left(x-3
   \log \left(1-e^x\right)\right)+\zeta (3)$$ and, if $x\to \infty$, the only term left is $\zeta (3)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3}$.

Comment: No it's not in my interest because my maths level is the level of PC classe préparatoire ;) But thank you ! :)

Comment: In which lycée are you in *classe préparatoire* (if I may ask) ? May be you noticed that I am in France.

Comment: I was in a good one in Lyon. :)

Comment: If you *were*, what are you doing now ? I looked at your profile and I have been interested by the fact that you are concerned by quantum stuff. I started my career as a quantun chemist and I still work in this area. If you want, at any time, we discuss, you can find my e-mail address in my profile. Cheers.

Comment: I will send you a mail in few minutes. I don't like to show myself in front of everybody. :-)