# eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for a nondegenerate $L^2$ kernel

Tags: integral-equations

> Consider the symmetric $L^2$ kernel $K(x,t)=\log(1-\cos(x-t))$ for
> $0\leq x,t\leq 2\pi$ . Find the eigenvalues and corresponding
> eigenfunctions of $K(x,t)$

By general procedure we consider a Fredholm equation $$y(x)=\lambda\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-\cos(x-t))y(t)dt$$ $$\implies y(x)=\lambda\log 2\int_0^{2\pi}y(t)dt+2\lambda\int_0^{2\pi}\log\sin\left(\frac{x-t}{2}\right)y(t)dt$$ $$\implies y'(x)=2\lambda\int_0^{2\pi}\cot\left(\frac{x-t}{2}\right)y(t)dt$$ But in this way I'm unable to convert the equation into a Sturm-Liouville boundary value problem and then find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions . What is the alternative way to find the same for this problem ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: An angle of attack could be via the Fourier series $ \ln(\sin(x))=\ln(2)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1n \cos(2nx)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$K(x,t)=-2 \log \left( \sin \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( x-t \right) \right) \right)$ eigenvalues and eigenfunctions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962495/kx-t-2-log-left-sin-left-frac12-left-x-t-right-right-right)

Comment: See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3963548 in order to show that the transformation made by the OP of the other question is the same as yours. (references found with the formula searching tool approach0.xyz)

Comment: Any comment ? Don't forget that this site is based on dialog...