# $\sum$ and $\int$ in equality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

[image]

Who can explain to me this passage in the Equality?

Thank you in advance

Comment: They simply replaced the $\Gamma (\eta (x)) G( \eta(x), n, 2x \left | z - w \right |^{2})$ term in the integral with the sum you highlighted below it and, assuming a few conditions, swapped the positions of the integral and sum.

Comment: It just swapped summation sign and integral sign without explanation in the third mark on yellow. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged) for a justification.

Comment: But the functions in question are not positive.

Comment: I am stuck on a passage for a long time