# Interchanging the integral and the infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

I would like to know whether I can interchange the integral and the infinite sum as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} f_k(x)\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} f_k(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$
where
$$f_k(x) = (-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{c(ab)^{k}}{2(1+bx)^{k}}x^{k-c-1},$$
with $n \in \mathbb{C}$, $a \in (0,1]$, $b > 0$, and $c \in [0, 1]$.

Now according to Nate Eldredge's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged), for general $f_k$ , if $\int \sum |f_k| < \infty$ or $\sum \int |f_k| < \infty$ (by Tonelli the two conditions are equivalent), then $\int \sum f_k = \sum \int f_k$.

**My attempt**:
I tried to prove the second condition as follows:
\begin{align}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} |f_k(x)|\mathrm{d}x &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} {\binom{n}{k}} \frac{c(ab)^{k}}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-c-1}}{\left(1+b x \right)^{k}}\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} {\binom{n}{k}} \frac{c(ab)^{k}}{2} b^{c-k}\left[\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi c)}\frac{\Gamma(k-c)}{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(1-c)}\right] \\
& = \frac{b^{c}}{2}\frac{\pi c}{\sin(\pi c)}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} {\binom{n}{k}} a^{k} \left[\frac{\Gamma(k-c)}{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(1-c)}\right].\quad (1)
\end{align}

I could not prove that the last expression in $(1)$ is $< \infty$.

Is my attempt on the correct track? If yes, how to prove that the RHS of $(1)$ is $< \infty$? If no, is there an another way to prove that the integral and the infinite summation can be interchanged?

Comment: Why don't you try the $k$ summation first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove that $(1)$ is finite you just have to compute the radius of convergence of a power series, namely
$$ an\,\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(1-c,1-n; 2;-a\right). $$
Since by the ratio test such radius of convergence equals one, the exchange of $\int$ and $\sum$ is allowed for any $a\in(0,1)$ and the $a=1$ case can be studied as a separate instance.

The exchange of $\int$ and $\sum$ in the $a\in(0,1)$ case then leads to the identity

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}cx^{-1-c}\left(1-\left(\frac{1+(1-a)bx}{1+bx}\right)^n\right)\,dx=cb^c\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k+1}a^k\binom{n}{k} B(c,k-c) $$
wher $B$ is Euler's Beta function. Both sides equals
$$ \frac{\pi nac b^c}{\sin(\pi c)}\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(1-c,1-n;2;a\right)=\frac{\pi n c b^c a(1-a)^{c+n}}{\sin(\pi c)}\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(c+1,n+1;2;a\right)$$
where the last identity is a consequence of [Euler's transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Transformation_formulas).

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on how did you reach to the Gauss hypergeometric function? Also, I notice that $a$ in the last expression (as an argument of the Gauss hypergeometric function), while in the first expression of your answer $-a$ is there as an argument of the Gauss hypergeometric function.

Comment: @User31443: I exploited the definition of $\phantom{}_2 F_1$ through Pochhammer symbols, which are ratios of values for the $\Gamma$ function. The exchange between $a$ and $-a$ is simply due to the fact that considering $\left|f_k(x)\right|$ in place of $f_k(x)$ turns a $(-1)^{k+1}$ into a $1$, but the hypergeometric structure of the involved series stays the same.

Comment: Oh, I see now! Yes, showing the convergence of radius is $1$ works.

Comment: I thought I got the relation with the hypergeometric function, but I didn't! $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} {\binom{n}{k}} a^{k} \left[\frac{\Gamma(k-c)}{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(1-c)}\right] = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} {\binom{n}{k}} \binom{k-c-1}{k-1} a^{k}$. Now the right hand of the previous equation is going to $\infty$ (I checked using MATLAB). Am I missing something here?

Comment: @User31443: do not write everything in terms of binomial coefficients, write the binomial coefficient as $\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{k!\Gamma(n-k)}$, instead. The pattern of a $\phantom{}_2 F_1$ will become evident. And recall that $B(c,k-c)=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(k-c)}{\Gamma(k)}$, while you wrote something different.

Comment: Thanks. I could obtain the expression with the hypergeometric function. One final query: How to obtain the convergence conditions at $a = 1$?

Comment: @User31443: at $a=1$ both sides are simple to evaluate by performing $\sum$ first then $\int$ or the opposite.