# Show that $\int\limits_0^2x^{-1}e^{-x} dx$ does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to show that the integral

> $$I:=\int\limits_0^2x^{-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx$$

diverges.

---

**My attempt:** We know that the problem is in the $x \to 0$ part so we have that $x \to 0$ implies $e^{-x} \to 1$ and $x^{-1} \to \infty$. We have that the function is not defined at zero so if we set this integral correctly we have that

$$I= \lim_{\xi \to 0}\int_\xi^2x^{-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx $$

I think is not possible to interchange the series of $e^x$ with the integral because it is a divergent integral of a series. (Is this correct? Thinking in the answer given [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged)).

We can use that $$E\mathrm i(-x) = \int x^{-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx+\mathrm{Const.}$$

So $$I = E\mathrm i(-2) - \lim_{\xi \to 0}E\mathrm i(-\xi)$$

Can anyone set a hint for what can I do?

Comment: You could compare it to $x^{-1}e^{-2}$.

Comment: Using that $x^{-1}e^{2}> x^{-1}e^{-x}$ and that $ln(x) \to \infty$? @JonasMeyer

Comment: But I don't expect that the integral converges. Clearly diverges. I'm trying to prove it.

Comment: @Rafael: Check your inequality.  And you mean $e^{-2}$?

Comment: No, I just mislead the inequality. If $x^{-1}e^{-2} < x^{-1}e^{-x}$ then using that the integral preserves inequality we have that the integral in $x^{-1}e^{-2} $ goes to infinity and then we must have that the integral in $x^{-1}e^{-x}$ goes to infinity?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I think I get it. Post this hint as an answer and I'll accept it. It is a very usefull one and solves the problem completely. Thanks a lot for your hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x^{-1}e^{-x} \ge x^{-1}e^{-1}$ on $(0,1),$ and $\int_0^1 x^{-1}\,dx = \infty,$ we have $\int_0^1 x^{-1}e^{-x}\,dx=\infty.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}$ for $x\in (0,2]$. Then $g$ can be made continuous at $x=0$ by defining $g(0)=-1$.

But then $$\int_{\xi}^2 x^{-1}e^{-x}\,dx = \int_{\xi}^2 g(x)\,dx + \int_{\xi}^2 \frac{dx}{x}$$

Since $g$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ you get:

$$\lim_{\xi\to 0+}\int_{\xi}^2 x^{-1}e^{-x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{2}g(x)\,dx + \lim_{\xi\to 0+} \int_{\xi}^{2}\frac{dx}{x}$$

Basically, $x^{-1}e^{-x}$ behaves "like" $\frac{1}{x}$ when $x$ is near zero.

Comment: It's $+$. We have $$x^{-1}e^{-x}= g(x)+\frac{1}{x}.$$ This is a very direct formula. 
@MathOverview

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
\begin{align}
\lim_{\xi\to 0}\int_\xi^2x^{-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx
=&
\lim_{\xi\to 0}\int_\xi^2x^{-1}D_x\big(-e^{-x}\big)\mathrm dx
\\
=&
\lim_{\xi\to 0}\left[
x^{-1}(-e^{-x})\Big|_{\xi}^{2}-\int_\xi^2D_x\big(x^{-1}\big)\big(-e^{-x}\big)\mathrm dx
\right]
\\
=&
\lim_{\xi\to 0}\left[
\frac{1}{x}(-e^{-x})\Big|_{\xi}^{2}
-
\int_\xi^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)(-e^{-x})\mathrm dx
\right]
\\
=&
\lim_{\xi\to 0}\left[
\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2}(e^{-2})+\frac{1}{\xi}(e^{-\xi})}_{\to \infty}
+
\underbrace{\int_\xi^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)(e^{-x})\mathrm dx}_{<\infty}
\right]
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

By convexity $e^{-x}\geq \max(1-x,0)$, hence
$$ \int_{0}^{2}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \geq -1+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x} $$
trivially implies divergence.