# Interchange derivative and summation?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives, summation

I would like to know, if we have: 
$$I=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\frac{1}{a+k}, ~~x, a>0$$

then interchange order of derivative and summation, 
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \binom{x}{k}\frac{1}{a+k}$$
is valid?

Comment: it is valid if your second series converges uniformly. Take a look [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/uniform.pdf).

Comment: See also: [When can a sum and integral be interchanged?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83721/2736)