# Interchanging Integral and Summation signs

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

So, I know there are a few functions that don't have elementary antiderivatives, and the way I approach some of these problems is by integrating the Taylor series. In the process, I usually interchange the (indefinite) integral sign and the summation sign. Example: 
$$
\int \sin(x)/x\ dx\,=\\\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}/(2n+1)!\ dx=\\\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((-1)^{n}/(2n+1)!)\int x^{2n} dx=\\C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}/((2n+1)!(2n+1)) 
$$
Is this valid?
when doing indefinite integrals of this sort (integrating Taylor series), when, if ever, will it be invalid to interchange the integration and summation signs?

Comment: It's usually appropriate to make such maneuvers, as both Riemann Integration and Lesbegue Integration are consistent under such swappages. I personally find baby Rudin to be a good guide for this question, although any elementary analysis text should do the question justice.

Comment: A power series can be integrated term-by-term.  That is, for Taylor series you can always interchange integration and summation with the circle of convergence.

Comment: Various answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged).