# Changing order of partial sum and integral all under limit to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, uniform-convergence

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{a}^b\  \sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x) \mathrm dx= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{a}^b f_k(x) \mathrm dx  $$

***Is this generaly true ?*** Integral is a sum , two sums can interchange, right?

I ve faced this in a proof of a theorem that says that integral of a uniformly convergent  sum  is equal to the sum of integral.
$\int \sum g_n = \sum \int g_n$   (   $ \sum g_n $ converges uniformly )

**The problem i am facing is that the stament in the title is used to prove the previous theorem.**

I dont think this is  a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged), this question is about a partial sum that changes order with an integral not an infinite

It is said the answer below is incorrect, can someone explain why

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged

Comment: It is not always true, but with uniform convergence you can.

Comment: @Atmos the first stament or the latter

Comment: The problem i am facing is that the stament in the title is used to prove the latter

Comment: The equality you wrote is not always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true (only after my edits) directly by the linearity of the integral and the definition of infinite sum.

What you wrote is correct - An integral and a (finite) sum can be interchanged with no further conditions. This is exactly the linearity of the integral.

Comment: Yeah it should be f sub k

Comment: That looks like a cheat. If i had sum that does to infinity i couldnt do it, but if the limit that goes to infinity  is in front  then i can :)

Comment: Please 1) do not accept a wrong answer, and 2) do not change the question such that you make an already posted answer wrong, or both.

Comment: I don't know what changes have occurred, but this answer is wrong. You cannot exchange the limit with the integral unless you know the sum of the functions converges uniformly. ONLY for finite sums, in general, can you interchange sum and integral.

Comment: @TedShifrin this is a finite sum there is just a limit in front of it ( if this makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the calculation attempt $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_a^bf_k(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_a^bf_k(x)dx.$$The first $=$ sign works provided each $\int_a^bf_k(x)dx$ is finite, since then$$\int_a^b\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_a^bf_k(x)dx$$and both sides have the same $n\to\infty$ behaviour (which might involve a limit not existing).

The second $=$ sign is true by the definition of the summation operator $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ as a limit of partial sums. In other words:

- If each $\int_a^bf_k(x)dx$ is finite then $\int_a^b\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)dx$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n\int_a^bf_k(x)dx$ are equal and have the same limit or each have no limit; and
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_a^bf_k(x)dx$ is either $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_a^bf_k(x)dx$ if that exists, or non-existent if it doesn't.

Comment: Why cant this be done to every infinte sum in integral, just changing it to a partial sum with a limit to infinity ?

Comment: @MilanStojanovic I'm not sure which counterexample you have in mind, but when at least one $\int_a^b f_k(x) dx$ isn't finite we have problems. There are also cases where $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)dx\ne\int_a^b\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)dx=\int_a^b\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)dx$.

Comment: @MilanStojanovic You can do this in every integral. What you cannot do is interchange the limit and the integral, that why the sum in the integral is not infinite.