# How does this infinite series $1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{10}+\cdots$ simplify to an integral $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^3}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

How does the infinite series below simplify to that integral?

$$1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{10}+\cdots=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^3}$$

I thought of simplifying the series to the sum to infinity of $\frac{1}{6n-5} - \frac{1}{6n-2}$, but this did not help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series  $$(1+x^3)^{-1}$$

Comment: It can be obtained by integrating term by term the infinite series expansion of $(1+x^3)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{dx}{1-(-x)^3}=\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-x)}^{3n}}}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{3n}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{3n}}dx}$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{3n}}{3n+1}}= 1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{10}+\cdots $$

Comment: For those who aren't clear on the first equality, it's a [geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Comment: Why can we interchange the sum and integration? what is the idea? thanks. @AlexisOlson If you are free, please respond. Thanks.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged).

Comment: @AlexisOlson Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

for $x$ real, $n\geq 0$ integer
\begin{align}\frac{1}{1+x^3}&=\frac{1-(-x^3)^{n+1}}{1-(-x^3)}+\frac{(-x^3)^{n+1}}{1-(-x^3)}\\
&=\frac{1-(-x^3)^{n+1}}{1-(-x^3)}+\frac{(-x^3)^{n+1}}{1+x^3}\\
\end{align}

For $x\neq 1$, $n\geq 0$ integer, \begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^3}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-x^3)^k\right)\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{(-x^3)^{n+1}}{1+x^3}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\int_0^1 (-x^3)^k\,dx\right)+\int_0^1 \frac{(-x^3)^{n+1}}{1+x^3}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{(-1)^k}{3k+1}+\int_0^1 \frac{(-x^3)^{n+1}}{1+x^3}\,dx\\
\end{align}

For $x\in[0;1],n\geq 0$, integer,
\begin{align}\frac{x^{3(n+1)}}{1+x^3}\leq x^{3(n+1)}\end{align}
and,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 x^{3(n+1)}\,dx=\frac{1}{3n+4}\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\left|\int_0^1 \frac{(-x^3)^{n+1}}{1+x^3}\,dx\right|\leq \frac{1}{3n+4}\end{align}
\begin{align}\left|\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^3}\,dx-\sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{(-1)^k}{3k+1}\right|\leq \frac{1}{3n+4}\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^3}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^k}{3k+1}}\end{align}

Comment: Why can we interchange $\sum$ and $\int$

Comment: Only finite sums (that is, not series) are used. You can interchange sum and integral signs when the sum involves finite number of terms.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Actually I was confused with the answer above yours one as there summation is over infinite terms.

Comment: My computation shows that series converges slowly.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lvert x\rvert<1$, let$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1}.$$Then $$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}=\frac1{1-x^3}.$$Therefore\begin{align}1-\frac14+\frac17-\frac1{10}+\cdots&=\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\\&=\int_0^1f'(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac1{1-x^3}\,\mathrm dx.\end{align}