# Laplace transform of a sum of Heaviside functions

Tags: integration, summation, laplace-transform

The questions is, find:
$$\mathcal{L}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\text{H}(t-n)\right]$$
I started by saying:
$$\mathcal{L}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\text{H}(t-n)\right]=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\text{H}(t-n)e^{-st}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^\infty\text{H}(t-n)e^{-st}dt$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^ne^{-ns}}{s}$$
My questions are:

- Can this summation be simplified in any way, or is this the best form?
- In this context I assume it is same to interchange the integral and summation, but are there any contexts where an integral and summation are NOT interchangeable?

Thanks

EDIT:
I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged) post talking about changing integrals and summations, but I am not sure I fully understand

Comment: You can take the $1/s$ outside the sum and you're left with a geometric series with $r = -e^{-s}$ which has a closed form.

Comment: @B.Goddard thank you very much. I get $$\frac{1}{s(1+e^{-s})}$$ Is this correct?

Comment: It looks right to me.