# Help Getting Started on Evaluating this Integral as a Power Series

Tags: calculus

I'm studying for the Math Subject GRE this fall, so I'm reviewing everything in Stewart's Calculus - Early Transcendentals 6th Ed. I've hit a brick wall with this problem, from the first section about power series representations of functions, in which I'm supposed to evaluate the following as a power series:

$$\int \dfrac{x - \arctan(x)}{x^3}dx$$

I don't know how to evaluate the $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ term as a power series, nor do I know what to do with $\dfrac{\arctan (x)}{x^3}$, since the lowest term in the series expansion for arctangent is $x$.

I suspect there must be some trick to this that I'm not seeing, so any help getting me started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, find the power series for $x-\arctan(x)$ then divide by $x^3$.

Comment: Oh...man. Well, I'd rather feel dumb now rather than later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int \dfrac{x - \arctan(x)}{x^3}dx
&=
\int \dfrac{x - \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}}}{x^3}dx\\
&=
\int \dfrac{x - (x + \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}})}{x^3}dx\\
&=
-\int \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}}}{x^3}dx\\
&=
-\int \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k-2}}{2k+1}} dx\\
&=
-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\int x^{2k-2} dx
\end{align}

Note: The step where I swapped the integral and summation operators requires some [condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged) to be true.