# $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n = \frac{1}{2}$ - Where have I gone wrong?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

Not sure where I've gone wrong in the following:

Consider the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-2x}\:dx = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Via some simple manipulation we find:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-2x}\:dx &= \int_0^\infty e^{-x} e^{-x} \:dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \left[ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n!} \right] \:dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} x^ne^{-x} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}  \:dx \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \Gamma(n + 1) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} n! = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n
\end{align}
And so, 
$$
 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n = \frac{1}{2}
$$
This is the famous [Grandi's Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series) which is divergent.

My question: Where have I gone wrong here? What rule/axiom/etc have I violated in my work in achieving this 'result'?

Comment: Well, you swapped a sum and an integral. Do you have a theorem to justify that?

Comment: You can't interchange the sum and the integral.

Comment: @JohnHughes - The Linearity of continuous integrals

Comment: @DavidGalea which is fine for a finite sum.  Interchanging an *infinite* sum on the other hand requires more justification, just like how interchanging integrals with one another would have required justification, or exchanging a limit inside an integral with outside.

Comment: @DavidGalea Linearity is for finite sums. Using some kind of additional structure, you can extend this to infinite sums in **certain circumstances**. You have found one of the circumstances where it fails.

Comment: @JMoravitz - Okay great - what theorems should I explore for this type of situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a great question and illustrates the subtleties in manipulating infinite sums. This interchange of limit and integration has violated Fubini's/Tonelli's theorem  [[Link]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged) . In particular

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty |(-1)^n| = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1 
$$

is divergent, as is

$$
\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left|\frac{1}{n!}x^ne^{-x}\right|\,dx = \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}x^ne^{-x}\,dx
$$
Therefore we cannot apply Fubini's/Tonelli's and would need to find some other justification of the interchange. Since we have proved that a divergent series converges, we will not be able to find a theorem justifiying the interchange.

Comment: Thank you Kyle.

Comment: Yes but that shows we can't apply Fubini's theorem. And Fubini's theorem doesn't give us a necessary condition.

Comment: @bjorn93 See the link. Fubini’s is an if and only if statement.

Comment: @KyleC The first answer in that link provides an example where the conditions for Fubini's theorem are violated yet the interchange is possible.

Comment: @bjorn93 Sorry, you are correct. Although the fact that we have proved a divergent series converges implies that no such interchange is justified. I have modified my answer to reflect this subtly.