# Finding solutions to non elementary integrals

Tags: calculus

For integrands such as $e^{-x^{2}}$ is it possible to transform into a Taylor series and exchange the summation with the integral similar to the problem sophomore's dream? $$\int e^{-x^{2}}dx=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x^{2})^{n}}{n!}dx$$ I have used the same method to evaluate $\int x^{x}dx$ and I have evaluated this integral numerically too getting the exact answer. Could this method be used to evaluate all non-elementary integrals?

Comment: Of relevance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged

Comment: @Deepak Thanks just what I need