# Show $E[X]-1\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty P[X\geq n]\leq E[X]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $X$ be any nonnegative random variable. Then show that 
$$E[X]-1\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P[X\geq  n]\leq E[X].$$

I was able to show the second inequality by 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P[X\geq n]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{ X\geq n}dP=\int_\Omega \sum_{1\leq n\leq X}1dP\leq \int_\Omega X dP =E[X].$$

However, the first inequality seems just impossible to show to me. Maybe there is a trick to show I guess. My first impression is that, since $P[X\geq 0]=1$, it may be possible so tackle with $$E[X]\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P[X\geq n]$$ but could not figure out.  I will thank to any suggestion or solution.  Thank you!

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690641/prove-that-f-in-l1a-leftrightarrow-sum-n-inftym-x-in-a-fx-geq-n/3691131) would help if you knows that $\mathrm{E}X=\int_0^{\infty }x \mathop{}\!d F_X$ for some non-negative r.v.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks(+1) !  that make sense even though that is a bit longer than I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already shown that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P[X\geq n] = \int_\Omega \sum_{1\leq n\leq X}1dP$$
You used the fact that $\sum_{1 \leq n \leq X} 1 \leq X$ to get the upper bound. For the lower bound, we just notice that $X - 1 \leq \sum_{1 \leq n \leq X} 1$ to get that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P[X\geq n] \geq \int_\Omega X - 1 dP = \mathbb{E}[X]-1.$$

Comment: Thank you! (+1 ) But I cannot see how $X-1\leq \sum_{1\leq n \leq X}1$. Could you give me a bit more detail?

Comment: The right hand side is the smallest integer less than or equal to $X$. There is always an integer in $[X-1, X]$ and so the smallest integer less than or equal to $X$ is always at least $X-1$.

Comment: Ah... I did not see that.. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, what the equalities you write at the start shows is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P[X \geq n] = E[\operatorname{floor}(X)]$. The inequalities are really then just the fact that $X - 1 \leq \operatorname{floor}(X) \leq X$.