# $P[X \geq n] = \int_{X \geq n} dP$, given that $E[X]$ exists, and $X$ is a nonnegative random variable: why is this always true?

Tags: probability

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698486/show-ex-1-leq-sum-n-1-infty-px-geq-n-leq-ex), there's an equality:

$P[X \geq n] = \int_{X \geq n} dP$, given that $E[X]$ exists, and $X$ is a nonnegative random variable.

Could someone please explain why the equality holds? Why are we allowed to put the (arbitrary) probability function $P$ under the differential? I have looked at the definitions of probability and distribution function, but they didn't help to see why the equality is true.

Thank you.

Comment: This is actually how the Lebesgue integral is constructed (i.e $\int 1_A dP = P(A)$ for any measurable set $A$)