# Prove $A = \{x ∈ X : f(x) ≥ a\}$ has finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space. I want to prove that is $f: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, non-negative and its integral on $X$ is finite, then $\forall a>0$ the set
$$A = \{x ∈ X : f(x) ≥ a\}$$
is $\mu-$finite (that is, $\mu (A) < \infty$). I think I could use [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-simple-function-approximation-theorem) lemma to prove this statement but I don't really know how to do it. Could someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $f\in L^1(A)\Leftrightarrow \sum_{n}^{\infty}m(\{ x\in A : f(x)\geq n \}) &lt; \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690641/prove-that-f-in-l1a-leftrightarrow-sum-n-inftym-x-in-a-fx-geq-n)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\int_X f\geq \int_A f\geq a\mu(A).$$