# Evaluate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\int _{0}^{1}nx^ne^{x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, fake-proofs

> Evaluate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\int _{0}^{1}nx^ne^{x^2}dx.$

I applied the [mean value thorem of integral](http://people.math.sc.edu/meade/Bb-CalcI-WMI/Unit5/HTML-GIF/MVTIntegral.html) to $\int _{0}^{1}nx^ne^{x^2}dx.$ We get $c\in (0,1):$

$$\int _{0}^{1}nx^ne^{x^2}dx=(1-0)nc^ne^{c^2}.$$ Taking limit ($\lim_{n\to \infty}$)on the both side,

We get, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _{0}^{1}nx^ne^{x^2}dx=\lim_{n\to \infty} nc^ne^{c^2}=0.$$

My answer in the examination was wrong. I don't know the correct answer. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your $c \in (0, 1)$ depends on $n$.

Comment: @sera but $f(x)=nx^ne^{x^2}$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$

Comment: @Unknownx The point $c$ is different for all $n$. You are applying the mean value theorem for integrals for different continuous functions.

Comment: By the way, are you also asking what the correct approach to showing this would be?

Comment: yes, How do I solve this kind of problem@Keen-ameteur

Comment: $f_n(x)=nx^ne^{x^2}$ does not converges uniformy to $0$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 nx^n e^{x^2} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705181/find-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-nxn-ex2-dx)

Comment: $$\int _{0}^{1}nx^ndx<\int _{0}^{1}nx^ne^{x^2}dx<\int _{0}^{1}nx^ne\,dx$$ shows that the limit has a finite value, between $1$ and $e$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the Taylor series of $e^{x^2}$ converges uniformly in $[0,1]$,
$$\int_0^1n x^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}dx=\int_0^1 n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k+n}}{k!}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac n{(2k+n+1)k!}\\=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac 1{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2k+1}{(2k+n+1)k!}.$$

The second term vanishes because
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2k+1}{(2k+n+1)k!}<\frac 1n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2k+1}{k!}.$$

> Hence $$e.$$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you come up eith the last equality?

Comment: @tommy1996q: which one ? Notice the minor typo, just fixed.

Comment: Where you equate $\frac{n}{(2k+n+1)k!}$ with those other 2 addendums, the last = you’ve written

Comment: @tommy1996q: reduce to common denominator.

Comment: Oh, I’d misread it and thought it was some obscure identity. Not gonna lie, feel really dumb right now

Answer (score 10):

Your proof is incorrect. The issue is that the $c$ which you choose may depend on $n$.

It turns out that the correct answer is in fact $e$. This is because for any continuous $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, we have

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_0^1 n x^n f(x) dx = f(1)$

This follows from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem as follows:

First, we prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_0^1 n x^n f(x) dx = f(1)$ for every $f$ of the form $f(x) = x^m$. We then extend this to all $f$ polynomial quite easily.

Suppose now that we have continuous $g : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Given arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, let $w = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Take polynomial $f$ s.t. $|f - g| < w$ (uniform norm) which is possible by Stone-Weierstrass, and take $N$ s.t. for all $n \geq N$, $\left|\int\limits_0^1 n x^n f(x) dx - f(1)\right| < w$. Then we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left| \int\limits_0^1 n x^n g(x) dx - g(1) \right| 
&\leq \left|\int\limits_0^1 n x^n g(x) dx - \int\limits_0^1 n x^n f(x) dx\right| + \left|\int\limits_0^1 n x^n f(x) dx - f(1)\right| + \left|g(1) - f(1)\right| \\[10pt]
&= \left|\int\limits_0^1 n x^n (g(x) - f(x)) dx \right| + |g(1) - f(1)| + \left|\int\limits_0^1 n x^n f(x) dx - f(1)\right| \\[10pt]
&< \left|\int\limits_0^1 n x^n (g(x) - f(x)) dx \right| + w + w \\[6pt]
&\leq \int\limits_0^1 n x^n \left|g(x) - f(x)\right| dx + 2w \\
&\leq w \int\limits_0^1 n x^n dx + 2w \\
&= w \frac{n}{n + 1} + 2w \\[6pt]
&<3w \\[6pt]
&= \epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation}

And therefore $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_0^1 n x^n g(x) dx = g(1)$

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively we could compute this limit directly via the substitution $u = x^{n+1}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1e^{u^{\frac{2}{n+1}}}\:du \to \int_0^1e\:du = e$$

by dominated convergence.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim _{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}nx^{n}\expo{x^{2}}\dd x & =
\lim _{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{1}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{1 - x} + \pars{1 - x}^{2}}\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim _{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{1 -\pars{n + 2}x}\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\expo{}\lim _{n \to \infty}{n \over n + 2} =
\bbx{\large\expo{}} \\ &
\end{align}

See [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late answer but maybe worth noting it.

Partial integration gives

$$I_n :=\int_0^1 \underbrace{nx^{n-1}}_{u'}\cdot\underbrace{xe^{x^2}}_{v}dx= \left.x^{n+1}e^{x^2}\right|_0^1- \underbrace{\int_0^1 x^n(1+2x^2)e^{x^2}dx}_{J_n=}=e-J_n$$

Now, $J_n$ can be easily estimated as follows
$$0\leq J_n \leq 3e\int_0^1x^ndx=\frac{3e}{n+1}\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Hence, $I_n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} e$.