# Moving an integral to the inside of a sum

Tags: integration, summation, fourier-series

I am deriving the fourier coefficient formula, and was wondering under what conditions I can move an integral from the outside of a sum to inside the sum? (as I have done below)
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n e^{i(n-m)x} \; dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}a_n e^{i(n-m)x} \; dx$$

Comment: Have you searched on this site ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged

Comment: $\sum |a_n|^{2} <\infty$ is sufficient.