# Moving an integral to the inside of a sum

Tags: integration, summation, fourier-series

I am deriving the fourier coefficient formula, and was wondering under what conditions I can move an integral from the outside of a sum to inside the sum? (as I have done below)
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n e^{i(n-m)x} \; dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}a_n e^{i(n-m)x} \; dx$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving an integral to the inside of a sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909581/moving-an-integral-to-the-inside-of-a-sum)

Comment: @Surb If $\sum|a_n|$ converges this is much less than DCT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the series $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n e^{i(n-m)x}$ is uniformly convergent on $[- \pi , \pi]$, then  you can move the integral from the outside of a sum to inside the sum.