# When can I say $\int\limits_{-T}^{T} \sum_n\sum_m f(m.n.t)dt=\sum_n\sum_m \int ^T_{-T}f(m,n,t)dt$?

Tags: summation

When can I say $\int\limits_{-T}^{T} \sum_n\sum_m f(m.n.t)dt=\sum_n\sum_m \int ^T_{-T}f(m,n,t)dt$?

All I know is that for each $t\in[-T,T]$, $\sum_n\sum_m f(m,n,t)$ is absolutely convergent, which I think is farily strong condition. But now I can't find any easy argument. Could you give me any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to remember this as a special case of the [Fubini/Tonelli theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini_theorem), where the measures are counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ and Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (or $[0,\infty)$ as you've written it here).  In particular, Tonelli's theorem says if $f_n(x) \ge 0$ for all $n,x$, then $$\sum \int f_n(x) \,dx = \int \sum f_n(x) \,dx$$ without any further conditions needed.  (You can also prove this with the monotone convergence theorem.)

Then Fubini's theorem says that for general $f_n$, if $\int \sum |f_n| < \infty$ or $\sum \int |f_n| < \infty$ (by Tonelli the two conditions are equivalent), then $\int \sum f_n = \sum \int f_n$.  (You can also prove this with the dominated convergence theorem.)

Source: [When can a sum and integral be interchanged?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged)