# Can you swap the integral and the sum to get this conclusion?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable for $n = 1,2,\dots$ Let $a_n = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n|$ for $n = 1,2,\dots$ and assume that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$. Prove that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges almost everywhere.

This essentially becomes $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n| < \infty$. The question is, can one interchange the integral and the sum? We've talked so much about interchanging limits and integrals with the convergence theorems, but what about for a sum? What would (or would not) allow me to do that here? Is that the right approach? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the first answer here (or the second one that uses the MCT): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged. After interchanging the integral and sum you still would need to explain why that implies convergence almost everywhere of the series.

Comment: Well I think it's obvious at that point. You have $\int \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |f_n|| < \infty$. One could just take the derivative of both sides to remove the integral, and you'd have the result. @folouerofkaklas

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but you can't take the derivative of that. You could  consider the set where the series doesn't converge and show it has measure zero.

Comment: why couldn't you? It's an integral, so it would cancel out?

Comment: The limits of integration are fixed.

Comment: @folouerofkaklas oh you're right. Hmm, well how would I show where the series doesn't convergence has measure 0?

Answer (score 1):

By using the triangle inequality and monotonicity of integrals, and then [MCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) (see the addendum below) to exchange summation and integral we obtain
$$\int\bigg|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n\bigg|dx\leq \int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n|dx\underbrace{=}_{\textrm{MCT}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int|f_n|dx<\infty$$
Since this implies $|f|=|\sum_{n \in\ \mathbb{N}}f_m| \in \mathcal{L}^1(dx)$, by the properties of functions in $\mathcal{L}^1$ then
$$\implies f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n \in \mathcal{L}^1(dx)$$
which means that $f$ is a.e. $\mathbb{R}$-valued.

---

As an addendum, it is straightforward to see how MCT leads to the result about sums. Set $s_M=\sum_{n=1}^M|f_n|$, (partial sums as a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$) you have
$$\int \sup_{M \in \mathbb{N}}s_M d\mu = \sup_{M \in \mathbb{N}} \int s_M d\mu = \sup_{M \in \mathbb{N}} \int \sum_{n=1}^M|f_n|d\mu \underbrace{=}_{\textrm{linearity}} \sup_{M \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{n=1}^M\int |f_n|dx$$
and $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|f_n|\in \mathcal{L}^1(dx)$ because it has been assumed that
$$\sup_{M \in \mathbb{N}}\sum^M_{n=1}\int|f_n|d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int|f_n|d\mu<\infty$$

Comment: we haven't covered Beppo Levi, so I couldn't use this.

Comment: Anyway MCT is a generalization of Beppo Levi's.. so if you can use MCT you can use Beppo Levi..

Comment: My instructor wouldn't allow it because we haven't mentioned it or discussed it.

Comment: I modified it by citing only MCT

Comment: It is unclear how you use MCT. MCT involves the limit and the integral, not the sum. I am sorry but this answer is not going to suffice for me.

Comment: I think there can't be misunderstandings now, it's even pedantic. If you still don't get it don't hesitate to ask for clarifications!