# Let $s:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be the function $s(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(kx)$. Calculate $\int_{-\pi}^\pi s(x) \ dx.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $s:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be the function $s(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(kx)$ where $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is an absolutely convergent series. Calculate $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi s(x) \ dx.$$

We want to compute $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(kx) \ dx$$ and what I would like to do is to conclude that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(kx) \ dx= \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(kx) \ dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \left(F(k\pi) - F(-\pi k)  \right)$$ where $F$ is the antiderivative of $\cos$ i.e. $\sin$. So $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi s(x) \ dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \left(\sin(k\pi) - \sin(-\pi k)  \right) = 0.$$

Can I just use conclude this since of the absolute convergence here?

Answer (score 1):

if $\sum a_k$ converges absolutely what can you conclude about the convergence of $\sum a_k \cos{kx}$?
also see [When can a sum and integral be interchanged?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged)