# For $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}nxe^{-nx^2}$, evaluate $\int\limits_{-1}^{1}f(x)\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

For $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}nxe^{-nx^2}$, evaluate $\int\limits_{-1}^{1}f(x)\, dx$

**What I have done:**

for every $x \in \mathbb{R}, $ series is uniformly convergent. So we have
$$\int\limits_{-1}^{1}f(x)\, dx=\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}nxe^{-nx^2}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-1}^{1}nxe^{-nx^2}=0$$

If this approach is not OK please let know. For the alternative way, please give me a hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see immediately from the definition of $f(x)$ that it is an odd function, i.e. $f(-x)=-f(x)$. The same result follows from the fact that integrating an odd function over a symmetrical interval will result in $0$.

Your methodology is completely fine aswell.

Comment: Cameron. is it possible to interchange the integral and series?

Comment: @user62498 In your scenario, yes. If you want more about the conditions under which they are interchangeable, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged .

Comment: Cameron,Thanks for  your answer and  this reference