# Calculate $ \sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+2} $

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble solving this sum.
Can't figure out what I'm dong wrong.
[image: the sum:]

Thanks!

Comment: I'd start with having definite integrals, so plesae put limits there

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Also, while there is no problem with it here, it's always better to justify the exchange of limits. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged With the correct integration bounds you will find the answer. Note that your primitive is not $0$ for $x=0$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E1+x%2F%281%2Bx%5E3%29 I am EEE student

Comment: $\left[\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}\right]_0^1=\frac\pi3\ne\frac\pi6=\left.\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}\right|_{x=1}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left[-\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|x+1\right|\right)}{3}+\dfrac{\ln\left(x^2-x+1\right)}{6}+\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{\sqrt{3}} \right]_{0}^{1}\\
= \dfrac{{\pi}}{2{\cdot}3^\frac{3}{2}}-\dfrac{6\ln\left(2\right)-\sqrt{3}{\pi}}{18}
\approx 0.3735507278914242
$$

Answer (score 1):

The term $\displaystyle\left.\int f(x)\, dx \right|_{x=a}$ makes no sense since the antiderivative of a function is not unique, you need to consider the integration constant. If $\displaystyle\int f(x)\, dx = F(x)+C$ then $\displaystyle\left.\int f(x)\, dx \right|_{x=a} = F(a)+C$ is not determined until you specify $C$.

That's what definite integrals are for, you should use $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3n+2}=\int_{0}^1 x^{3n+1}\, dx$